# GCM notifications suddenly stopped working , Not recieving notifications at all

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have created an app with GCM notifications and moved it to live it was working well for quite some time, 2, 3 months then suddenly stopped receiving notifications. Gone the code but not able to understand what went wrong and where should I fix. 
Here is my manifest.xml

```
    <activity android:name="com.ind.MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.ind.ChaptersActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.ind.SectionsListActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.ind.SectionDetailActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.ind.RuleDetailsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.ind.PartsListActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.ind.PartsDetailActivity"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_web_dev" android:name="com.ind.Circulars"/>
    <activity android:name="com.ind.CircularsDetailsActivity"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_web_design" android:name="com.ind.Notifications"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/title_activity_web_maintain" android:name="com.ind.PressNotes"/>        
    <activity android:name="com.ind.UpdateDetailsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.ind.NotificationDetailsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.ind.UpdatesActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.ind.Comparision"/>
    <activity android:name="com.ind.ComparisionActivity"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="com.ind"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>
```

Please let me know is there is something wrong.

From Database I could see that devices are registering properly, and all see the same thing from logs even.

Comment: Were there any error logs in your app server responses?

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that you correctly proccesses these things:

1. **NotRegistered** is error code from GCM server. Getting this code you should immediately remove **regId** from your database
2. **cannonical_ids** is a signal that you should replace **regId** with new one
3. You must request new **regId** from GCM while updating your client app

Also if you have all regIds in your database, you can try to send test push to them and check what is respone from GCM. You can use my [dev push server](http://1-dot-sigma-freedom-752.appspot.com/) for these purposes.